# Do I need to sanitise HTML from MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, dompurify

I am using the MediaWiki API to get contents of wikipedia pages and display them on a webpage.

Normally I would just use the DOMPurify library to sanitise any HTML before I render it however for some reason when I use DOMPurify with any incoming HTML it ruins it so that the Wikipedia stylesheets no longer work - it works just fine without sanitisation.

So my question is, is it even necessary to sanitise the MediaWiki HTML, will there not already be security measures in place to make sure any data I access is safe?

Answer (score 0):

For Wikipedia, you probably don't need to, although it depends on how exactly you are using it. For MediaWiki in general, it depends on the site operator, some MediaWiki extensions do allow user-generated Javascript in the page content.